# Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLContext'

Tags: ios, google-signin

I am integrating Google Sign-In in my ios Swift app. I am following the official instructions on the google developer page here(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift )

Here is my Bridging Header:

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h


#endif /* Header_h */

#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
```

When I call the line in my `AppDelegate.swift` function that has

```
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
```

in it. It says

```
 Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLContext'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35552770/3535399

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Google/*` pods are deprecated, you should use `pod GoogleAnalytics` or `pod GoogleSignIn` instead. You can't find `GGLContext` in those pods because it no longer exists since it no longer requires a `GoogleInfo-Service.plist` file for Analytics or SignIn.

For SignIn you should use the clientID that was previously obtained in the *GoogleInfo-Service.plist* file to initialize

`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kClientID`

or if you are using Firebase

`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID`

For Analytics you should use the trackerID that was previously obtained in the *GoogleInfo-Service.plist* file or in the analytics panel to initialize

`let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().tracker(withTrackingId: kTrackerID)`

[Google SignIn docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

[Google Analytics docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please point to documentation that explains that?

Comment: Google iOS documentation tends to be outdated, the Analytics one shows the same process I described but the Google SingIn has a mix of the old and new method

Comment: Yes, I was searching through docs when I wrote my comment. Thank you for this answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 21):

Inside **Podfile.h,**

replace

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

with

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

Inside **BridgingHeader.h** file add the following two lines:

```
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
#import <Google/Core.h>
```

**Inside AppDelegate.swift,**

replace

```
import GoogleSignIn
```

with

```
import Google
```

This worked in my case.

Actually the pod 'Google/SignIn' has the required dependencies of Google needed to use GGLContext. These aren't present when installing cocoapods using pod 'GoogleSignIn'

Comment: @Thalatta: Upvote my answer, if it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: Incredible that even today the documentation is outdated. Thx for this :D

Comment: @andres.cianio I know, thanks to the saviour 'StackOverflow' :)

Comment: This is ridiculous :D

Answer (score 4):

The answer of Benjamin Jimenez  was the correct one, not the one marked as "correct" since it suggests to use deprecated version of libraries instead of moving on with the new versions and updating your project accordingly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46858690/3506788

One small addition to the solution though: if you use Firebase, make sure that you initialise Firebase before using this line:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17893176)

Comment: It does provide a solution to the problem, more precisely a clarification to a comment that is the beginning of the solution. Also it points out that the post marked as "solution" is absolutely not one and a bad practice on top of that (edit: " _was_ marked as solution" since it has been changed since my first post).
The system that prevents to comment an answer when the reputation is too low shows limits there in my opinion. That's not the topic of the discussion though. We can discuss about that privately instead of going of topic.

Comment: This comment was very helpful.