# Is there a way to use the pod 'Google/SignIn' without errors?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-signin

I am getting these thread warnings when using the pod.

[image]

Let me know if anyone knows how to prevent or get rid of these. Thanks for your time!

My current solution is answering a post here:
  [iOS Swift : error with google login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626693/ios-swift-error-with-google-login/47994892#47994892)

Let me know if there is any reason this is wrong.

Comment: You are getting a problem from an older version of the library. Should be fine with the latest version: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/69

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Thank you! I had a suspicion this was just a versioning issue. Google needs to fix up their documentation. I had to piece together everything I needed from documentation tat clearly was done at 3 hugely different time periods.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Checkout my answer on this thread at the bottom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626693/ios-swift-error-with-google-login/47994892#47994892